# How to show variations only which are in stock on shop page in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I don't want to show all attributes that are available, I just need to show those variations value which have stock saved on back-end.
Just like I have a variable named sizes, so i want to show the product as well as its available sizes, if a product has 5 different sizes, but two of its sizes has no stock then display only the other 3 sizes which are in stock, and if one product has 5 different sizes and all sizes are in stock then display all those sizes. Here is the code that I am using:

```
    echo '<div class="row m-0 justify-content-center">';
    $fabric_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_sizes');
    foreach ( $fabric_values as $fabric_value ) {
        echo '<button class="btn btn-circle btn-lg rounded-circle">'."$fabric_value->name" . '</button>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
```

Here is the snap:
[See The screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2AF1.png)
This shows all the attributes which I have stored before.
What's the solution, if anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
global $product;

        $taxonomy    = 'pa_sizes'; // The product attribute taxonomy
        $sizes_array = []; // Initializing
        // Loop through available variation Ids for the variable product
        foreach( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
            $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id ); // Get the WC_Product_Variation object
            if( $variation->is_purchasable() && $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
                $term_name = $variation->get_attribute( $taxonomy );
                $file_list[$term_name] = $term_name;

            }
        }

        /*
         * Loop through the array and print all the values
         */
        if(is_array($file_list)){
            sort ($file_list);
            foreach($file_list as $file){ 
                echo '<button class="btn btn-circle btn-lg rounded-circle">' . $file . '</button>';
            }
        }
        else{
            echo '<p style="font-size:12px;">No Sizes Available</p>';
        }
```